# Cannot remove .git/: Directory not empty

Tags: bash, git, delete-file, rm

I have a .git/ folder that I'd like to delete. However, it isn't possible because there is a puzzling file into it which is not reachable.

Below is my try:

```
$ rm -rf .git/ 
rm: cannot remove '.git/': Directory not empty   
$ rm -r .git/
rm: descend into directory '.git/'? y
rm: cannot remove '.git/t8QVta1': No such file or directory
rm: remove directory '.git/'? y
rm: cannot remove '.git/': Directory not empty
$ ls -l .git/
ls: cannot access '.git/t8QVta1': No such file or directory
total 0
?????????? ? ? ? ?            ? t8QVta1
$
```

I have no idea what is the 't8QVta1' file and all of the question marks.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like either a permission issue or corrupted data.

Comment: This kind of nonsense filename is sometimes generated by software that needs to keep *a* name around, for some particular purpose known only to that software, but to avoid names that someone else might want. In that case the file is probably owned by, and usable only by, that other software. But it's preventing you from removing the directory. You'll need to find out what this other (non-Git) software is and what to do about it. (Or, of course, it could just be on-disk corruption.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?????????? ? ? ? ?...` output of ls may indicate that you are missing the correct permissions to access this file. If this is the problem, you could try giving yourself permissions over the parent directory and its children with the following command:

```
sudo chmod -R g+x .git/
```

Comment: I cannot do that because it is on a mounted (FUSE) folder. But that explain the problem so thank you so much!! I just need to SSH to this folder where I have all the permissions to delete it.

Comment: The mounted-via-FUSE thing explains it: some process/thread has the file open and the FUSE code (which doesn't hold the file open itself to avoid running out of descriptors) needs to make sure the *kernel* doesn't remove the file so it's tried to hide it away. Given that it's inside the `.git` directory, this might be some long-lived Git process running outside the environment in which you're using the FUSE-mount.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a non-empty folder use `-rf` flags

> $ rm -rf .git

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to tell that of course I've tried that. I add this to my post.